# Effective Theory of FQH Edge State

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-order, quantum-hall-effect

When I was learning Xiao-Gang Wen's paper about the edge theory of Fractional Quantum Hall(FQH) state, I had one question. The paper's link is as below:\
http://dao.mit.edu/~wen/pub/edgere.pdf

As clearly shown in the paper (eqn 2.7), density operator of edge state $\rho_k$ satisfies $U(1)$ Kac-Moody algebra. Also, the current operator $j_k^+$ also satisfies the same algebra (eqn 2.27).

My question is why $\rho_k$ and $j_k^+$ satisfy the same algebra? They must be closely related, is it? As shown in the last sentence below (eqn 2.27), the author said they are the same because of charge conservation. I don't understand this. Why it is related with charge conservation.

Thank you in advance.